# Best way to handle link for login-protected pages

Tags: seo, links, 302-redirect

I have a e-learning website with free and paid courses.

On my course page, there is link to the lessons.

If it is a paid course, when you click on the link you are redirected to the shop.
See this [example](https://hvac-learning.com/courses/air-conditioners-technology-part-1/).

For my SEO, is there a better way to handle internal links that you can only access when logged on ?

Actually I use a rel="nofollow" (and learndash as LMS). I fear that too many 302 on my courses is not good.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to consider

1. do you want the contents indexed, ie viewable in searches.
2. what should happen when someone clicks on such a link.

My suggestions are

1. That only a summary page should be indexed. To do this, you need to remove all internal links to them. Have a login button, after which the links are revealed. Don't mark them `display=none`. They should be absent altogether before logging in.
2. that they should return 403

> The HTTP 403 Forbidden response status code indicates that the server understands the request but refuses to authorize it.

From [developer.mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/403)

Comment: 1. I want the course page to be indexed, not the lessons.
2. It should not be a link, just the title of the lesson.
The problem is that I used Learndash as the Learning Management System. I will change their code to align with what you suggest (purely removing the link). Thanks for the hints !